# golang: how to make net.Dialer() send packets from specified 'LocalAddr' not loopback? Where's bind?

Tags: go, sockets, udp

(Env: bare metal x86_64 fresh unmodified Ubuntu 22.04LTS)

I want to do the golang net.Dialer equivalent of the following Python code. This Python insures the MAC address of the ethernet device 'enp1s0f1' appears in the source part of the TCP packet so that each transmitted packet increments the tx_unicast count as seen by `ethtool -S enp1s0f1`. tcpdump will NEVER show the packet leaving the loopback device i.e. "lo In  ifindex 1 00:00:00:00:00:00...":

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import time
import socket

def send_tcp_packet(dev, packet):
    # Create a raw socket
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_PACKET, socket.SOCK_RAW, socket.SOCK_RAW)

    # Bind the socket to the specific Ethernet device
    s.bind((dev, 0)) <--- MAGIC CALL HERE
    . . .
send_tcp_packet("enp1s0f1", ...)
```

Here's the golang equivalent I've coded:

```
func main() {  
  // Lookup ethernet device 'enp1s0f1'                                                                                                         
  ief, err := net.InterfaceByName("enp1s0f1")                                                                           
  if err!=nil {                                                                                                         
    panic(err)                                                                                                          
  }                                                                                                                     
  fmt.Printf("ief : %+v\n", ief)                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
  addr, err := ief.Addrs()                                                                                              
  if err!=nil || len(addr)==0 {                                                                                         
    panic(err)                                                                                                          
  }                                                                                                                     
  fmt.Printf("addr: %v\n", addr)                                                                                        
                                                                                                                        
  // for now hardcode 192.168.0.2; later use addr[0] since
  // I know addr[0]=='192.168.0.2/28'                                                                   
  bindAddr, err := net.ResolveIPAddr("ip", "192.168.0.2")                                                               
  if err!=nil || len(addr)==0 {                                                                                         
    panic(err)                                                                                                          
  }                                                                                                                     
                                                                                                                        
  // Make dialer s.t. it sends packets from 'bindAddr'                                                                  
  var d = &net.Dialer{LocalAddr: bindAddr,}                                                                             
  fmt.Printf("dialer bound to %v...\n", d.LocalAddr)                                                                    
                                                                                                                        
  fmt.Printf("dialing 192.168.0.2:2000 ...\n")                                                                                           
  conn, err1 := d.Dial("udp", "192.168.0.2:2000")
```

When I run this code:

```
ief : &{Index:3 MTU:1500 Name:enp1s0f1 HardwareAddr:08:c0:eb:d4:d1:6f Flags:...}
addr: [192.168.0.2/28 fe80::ac0:ebff:fed4:d16f/64]
dialer bound to 192.168.0.2...
dialing ...
2024/01/03 18:09:03 Failed to dial: <nil>
```

If I do not set `LocalAddr` in the dialer, the connection works but tcpdump reports the packets go through the loop back device.

What do I have to do to make Dialer send the UDP packet with the MAC address of 'enp1s0f1'? I've tried DialUDP with source and destination but to no avail.

The problem it seems,

- I'm missing a bind call? This may require root; for me no problem e.g. [bind](https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.21.5:src/syscall/syscall_linux.go;l=825). But all it would do is call socketopt() with BINDTODEVICE. Python has an equivalent and like golang **this has no effect w.r.t. to loopback. This cannot be the solution.**
- Or the dialer's resolver doesn't like 'bindAddr' (port missing)
- Or the dialer's LocalAddr was never intended for my use-case. 'LocalAddr' seems intended only to hold the source IP and port. The issue of the source MAC address and which ethernet device its transmitted from has nothing to do with 'LocalAddr'

Comment: I'm not sure yet what you're doing exactly, neither of these seem like the right approach. The Go code however can be fixed by using a udp address to dial a udp connection (though you probably want a udp listener in most cases, since you don't appear to be using a "connected" udp socket in python). If you want the raw bind calls, you can use the syscall package, however you need to be aware that blocking network calls don't work with the global network poller in the go runtime. (see the similar https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27410764/dial-with-a-specific-address-interface-golang)

Comment: The objective is: send a packet through a specified ethernet device 'enp1s0f1' seen by ip link show. The solution is verified when (1) tcpdump shows the packet having the source MAC address of enp1s0f1, and (2) ethtool -S enp1s0f1 shows the tx_unicast count steadily increasing as each packet is sent. This was frustratingly hard to do in Python. And it seems darn hard to do in golang. Somehow both APIs blow by the important point it's sometimes important to control the source part of the packet and from which ethernet device it's transmitted.

Comment: On linux the device from which packets leaves is a routing decision, not part of the socket, so it's not a normal part of the socket API in any language. In both cases you probably want the SO_BINDTODEVICE sockopt, not a raw socket (or deal with it in routing)

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like what you're looking for is not actually to create a raw socket, but rather bind a socket to a particular network device. This is a platform specific operation, but on Linux you can use the [`SO_BINDTODEVICE` sockopt](https://pkg.go.dev/syscall#BindToDevice).

Being platform specific, that is only exposed in a `syscall` package, which you can hook into via a `Control` option when [listening](https://pkg.go.dev/net#ListenConfig) or [dialing](https://pkg.go.dev/net#Dialer) a connection to avoid having to handle the raw socket in blocking mode. Since a normal UDP socket is in a listening state, you would want to make this with a listener:

```
listener := &net.ListenConfig{
    Control: func(network, addres string, c syscall.RawConn) error {
        var err error
        ctrlErr := c.Control(func(fd uintptr) {
            err = syscall.BindToDevice(int(fd), "enp1s0f1")
        })
        if ctrlErr != nil {
            return ctrlErr
        }
        return err
    },
}

pc, err := listener.ListenPacket(context.Background(), "udp", "192.168.0.2:0")
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

udpConn := pc.(*net.UDPConn)
...
```